# Increase max_stack_depth

Tags: database, windows, postgresql, stack

How can I increase PostgreSQL's max_stack_depth on Windows (10)?

I tried to increase it from postgresql.conf (current value is 2MB). But I can't make it higher than 3MB. If I set a higher value the PostgreSQL service won't start.

Comment: You could look into the [Windows Event Log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer) to see any errors.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY):

> Setting max_stack_depth higher than the actual kernel limit will mean
> that a runaway recursive function can crash an individual backend
> process. On platforms where PostgreSQL can determine the kernel limit,
> the server will not allow this variable to be set to an unsafe value.
> However, not all platforms provide the information, so caution is
> recommended in selecting a value.

So what is this limit on Windows? When you have that answer, you make  your configuration change in PostgreSQL.

Comment: This is not the answer. How can I increase this value? If I can do it by changing windows configuration then how?